# Creating Magento Site's Native Android Application

Tags: java, android, magento, android-intent

I have the following questions which I have researched a lot on [Google](http://google.com) as well as in [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) but found nothing::

1. I have to create a **Native Android Application** of a **Magento based Site**, and I have to use the same **database** of *Magento Site*. Now, I have found that we can't Access the PHP files of the Magento project as the access is denied. So how to call a Magento Login Function from the Android Client?
2. I have come to know that we have to call the function through using **XML-Connect** file in *Magento*. Please any one can give me a Example **how to call that file** and how?
3. **Last Parsing**. Which parser would be more handy? (DOM, SAX, SIMPLE XML Serialization parser?)
4. How to manage the Sessions with the Magento Store So that the user can add to cart items and could do Online Transaction.

Anyone who has worked on Magento Site's App Development provide some direction to move further. I am totally lost and getting nothing from the Online Research.

Any help would be highly Appreciated.
And Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not worked with Magento site. But I've worked with similar websites to connect to the mobile applications.

Short Answer: XML-Connect is the best way to minimize your work. And its easy to use API than connecting to the database using php files. For mobile applications, it is always advisable to use a simple xml format, however, in your case, you have to stick to xml-connect's protocol.

For some more information, see this link http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/develop-your-own-magento-mobile-application/

Comment: Thanks for Reply...Yes..i have gone through the link before that you provided and came to know that XMLConnect is helpful.But can you please tell me how to get login Authentication in the magento Store.

Comment: May be you should check their development blog in depth. I could see more info about the xml usage there. http://inchoo.net/category/mobile-development/android-development/

Comment: Yes..i have checked there..and the Examples provided their were not sufficient and many of them run with only errors...So not getting clear idea.